# Estimating the tangential and cross component of the galaxy's shear using Gnomonic projection

Tags: cosmology, mathematics, galaxy-cluster, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

I would like to know how I can estimate the **tangential** and **cross** component of the galaxy's **shear** using [Gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection)
of the right ascension and declination the galaxies relate to the center of galaxy cluster and estimate?

**Edit.** *Shear* is the second order moment of a galaxy's surface brightness. You can find more on the topic in the following [wiki on weak lensing](http://gravitationallensing.pbworks.com/w/page/15553259/Weak%20Lensing).

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by shear? When I read the title I thought about the shear in the galactic velocity fields and Oort's constants ...

Comment: @Walter shear is **the second order moment of galaxy's surface brightness**. You can find more exclusive explanation [here](http://gravitationallensing.pbworks.com/w/page/15553259/Weak%20Lensing)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are after: Do you mean you want to project the movement vectors of all galaxies in a galaxy cluster onto a plane which each galaxy then having a tangential and a radial component (the 3rd dimension we lost by projection), as well as a brightness. Once you have that, you want to somehow calculate the 2nd derivative of the brightness changes. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: So you basically are asking how to derive the components of optical transfer matrix, in particular the off-diagonal components, of the media between us and the observed galaxy (assuming some kind of ideal galaxy forms the original undistorted image)?

Comment: @planetmaker Your interpretation does probably make more sense :-)

Comment: Not sure we get a (quick) answer 6,5 years after it was asked and 2 months after the OP was last seen :D